# Необходимость статического IP для сервера

Tags: сервер

Если у меня будет статический ИП, то я могу использовать свой компьютер как сервер? Т.е. к моему компу смогут подключаться клиенты без всяких проблем?

Comment: А можно подробностей добавить что от куда и куда должно быть доступно и для каких целей (домашний сервер, офисный сервер, цод...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да смогут, но только ипе должен быть валидным. И осторожнее с безопасностью. Если с этим слабо, то для начала почитайте о безопасности. Помните, что помимо ваших клиентов крекеры тоже не спят!

Comment: Как понять валидный мой ип или нет?

Comment: да как????

Comment: валидный это тот что виден с мира, то бишь он выдается провайдером. Не валидный это локальный ипе. Если вы все поднимаете локально например в офисе какой то сервер то используйте не валидник. Ну а если он у вас например дома и вы поднимаете сайт, то к провайдеру чтобы он вам выдал валидный ипе адрес. Вы какую цель преследуете?

Comment: Заходите на любой онлайн сервис по проверке открытых портов на желаемом IP и проверяете тот порт, который считаете что открыт у вас. Например запустите какой-нибудь сервер игры и проверяйте на доступность извне его порт. Если у вас "серый/невалидный" IP, то порт будет недоступен.

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос достаточно абстрактен и практически не имеет ответа, к сожалению.
Могу описать только некоторые случаи из практики для пользовательских и корпоративных сетей

**Один**

У вас есть роутер от вашего провайдера, если в нем есть функционал с port forwarding то вы можете перекинуть пор вашего веб сервера (Apache/Nginc/Tomcat etc) с роутера на сервер (делается у каждого производителя по разному, такова индустрия).

Узнав свой внешний IPv4 можно подключатся к вашему приложению (пусть будет так) с "внешки", приходишь к другу вводишь свой IPv4 адрес в браузере и можешь зайти на сервис.

Можно купить DNS имя у того же провайдера или у 3й стороны и прописать там свой текущий IPv4 адрес.

Если в контракте с провайдером у вас указано использование dynamic IP то с течением времени адрес конечно сменится и вам нужно будет менять его в вашем DNS сервисе.

НО - есть DDNS провайдеры, которые позволяют имея динамический IPv4 (IPv6) адрес сохранять DNS подключение. Это удовольствие конечно не бесплатное и требует поддержки со стороны руоутера, где нужно указать ваши детали для учетной записи. Пример такого сервиса [www.noip.com](http://www.noip.com)

**Два**

Если у вас облачные сервера, то там наверняка уже будет статичный IP, если нет то можно и купить, когда речь идет о вашем сервисе, предположим магазин, который себя окупает.

**Три**

Если вы компания у которой своя стойка в ЦОД, то вам провайдер обязан предоставить статичный IP. Читаем контракт.

**Четыре-в-бесконечность**

Наличае статичного IP НЕ гарантирует внешний доступ есть еще - routing/firewall, политики безопасности и фильтрации трафика на гос уровне.

Comment: Человек скорее имел ввиду возможность использовать домашний компьютер как сервер.

Comment: @Rootware Я это предположил, но те то читают вопрос могут думать о своем -- брал свой опыт, описал в ответе. Автору посоветовал бы расширить вопрос или показать конкретный пример.

Comment: Hellseher, ну из глубины вопроса уже было понятно, что у человека "пользовательские потребности". А так да, вопрос вы раскрыли широко.